# Titles on the left Pane of Eclipse Preference Window not displaying in Mac OS X

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I launched my eclipse IDE (Version 4.15.0), have been using it to code in java and everything has been working fine. When I wanted accessing the preference window under Eclipse > Preferences, the window opened perfectly fine but the titles which are usually on the left pane that enables you browse through the dialogue pages weren't there.

[image]

Please how can I fix this?

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Questions about problems with programming tools such as Eclipse **are** on topic here.

Comment: Eclipse 2020-03 (4.15) works OK here on macOS 10.15.4. Is this just the normal dark theme you are using? Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a message.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash The system preferences were never accessed. I did a restart and reinstall both to no avail. Thanks for your inconclusive help.

Comment: @greg-449 Yes, its just a normal dark theme. I just checked the .log file, the message I saw -
"System property http.nonProxyHosts has been set to local by an external source. This value will be overwritten using the values from the preferences."

Comment: That log message is expected, it isn't the problem

Comment: Possiblly [this bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=561487) which applies to older versions of macOS

Comment: As a workaround, scroll up in the tree area.

Answer (score 0):

@Arvind - I am also facing the issue. As a workaround, I clicked on search button, which is on the right hand side of the toolbar. And then type "Preferences". Now, you can select your choice of preferences. Cheers.